# Include files in php showing error

Tags: php, include

I am having a folder called `"db"`. where it contains 3 files which calls from the mail file `"connect.php"`.

I created a new file in root directory and wrote a function

```
include "db/connect.php");
echo $connstring;
```

Here I am not getting any output, the `$connstring` is defined in another file in `"db"` folder named as `"config.php"` which is included in beginning of the `"connect.php"`

Comment: nothing is showing or you're  getting an error. Which is it? What is the error?

Comment: a bracket is missing at the include statement

Comment: @dany in fact you don't need brackets at all with include/require so you could say there's a bracket that shouldn't be there too ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exactly was looking hot to include the files from different directories correctly.

This is how I got the code to achieve this from one of the project on Zend.

set_include_path( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(**FILE**))))
                  . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' );

Answer (score 4):

You have written wrong code for include function.

You should try this,

```
include ("db/connect.php");
echo $connstring;
```

Comment: Or this: include `'db/connect.php';` The PHP documentation doesn't explicitly tell it but you don't need brackets with include/require